# Why is Cura printing vases much slower than the printer can go?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing

I have been trying to tune a new filament, on my CR-10 V2, by printing vases, but Cura won't let me print the vases any faster than 10-15 mm/s even when I input all the print speeds to about 65 mm/s. This problem only occurs when I try to print with a single parameter/wall and no matter what I do Cura doesn't print it any faster.

Does anyone know if there is a feature that forces it to print slower than it's being told to, or if this problem is a result of some kind of protective feature and if it can be overridden?

Answer (score 3):

Minimum Layer Time. By default it's 5 seconds, and some printer profiles have it much higher, e.g. 10 seconds. This is to allow sufficient time for the previous layer to cool before laying down the next layer, but it's way too high. Make sure you have good cooling (possibly blowing a large room fan on the print volume if needed) and you can turn it down significantly. This is unlikely to work for very tiny details, where 3-4 is about the lowest you can safely go, but in a vase spread out over a large area it should be practical to cool it even with fast printing.